# Kibana: get records only if condition persist for given span of time

Tags: kibana, dsl, elk

I'm facing a querying problem with Kibana: I want to be returned all the records that match a given condition but only if they match it for at least a given span of time. Something like:

`Clock > 50 and Vents is "off" ***for 20s minimum***`

I tried to explore the DSL querying language, and there I found that's possible to select all the records that match the condition AND that fall in a given span of time (let's say, between the firs of the year and today), but that's not what I'm looking for.
I'm looking for the records that match the condition FOR AT LEAST a given span of time, whenever that happened,

is it possible to make such a query in Kibana?

Comment: The `kql` tag is reserved for Kusto Query Languages

Comment: Sinceres thanks for better specifying my question